# elasticsearch: What is the best way for partial updates?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got a mapping like this:

```
{
  "properties":{
    "staticField1": ...
    "staticField2": ...
    ...
    "staticFieldN": ...
    "currentNumbers": {
      "properties": {
        "highFrequencyUpdateField1": ...
        "highFrequencyUpdateField2": ...
        "highFrequencyUpdateField3": ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So there are many `staticFields`, which are updated almost never, but some fields in the `currentNumbers` node, which must be updated every few minutes.

I currently `POST` a partial update with only the `currentNumbers` node, but since everything is in one large document here, this will internally reindex the complete document of course.

What I want to achieve is some way of

- replacing only the `currentNumbers` node without elasticsearch needing to reindex all `staticFields`.
- *and* being able to query documents by a combination of `highFrequencyUpdateFields` and `staticFields` (so I cannot treat them as completely seperate entities)

From what I've read in the docs, I get the following two options:

- the "nested" datatype
- parent/child docs

Regarding parent-child relationships: That seems to come with worse query performance, which I don't want to sacrifice here.

What I couldn't find in the docs: Does `nested` help me here in regard to indexing performance, i.e. does it *not* reindex the entire document if I post a partial update with only the `currentNumbers` node?

I think this is probably a frequent usecase for elasticsearch, so I hope there maybe are better ideas on how to structure the mapping ;).

Comment: It seems to be in the docs now (maybe it was there all the time and I've just not seen it): https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html:

>"Not only that, because of the way that nested objects are indexed, joining the nested documents to the root document at query time is fast—almost as fast as if they were a single document."

So `nested` does not help performance-wise. Hence, two separate indices (one for the relatively static data, one for the high frequency updates) and joining them in the application is probably the way to go.